# how to authentificate through withings api using sribe in java

Tags: java, api, oauth, scribe, withings

I use scribe librabry for java , that's a library that simplificate oAuth procedure.

I try to write a code for authenticate me in the withings api with java with scribe but i have always the same problem : "Invalide Token".
I don't know what to write in the verifier param in scribe ....

Thanks for your response.

Bye.

Comment: it has been a long time since i worked on it sorry, but i'm sure of one thing is that i used this link for implement oauth protocol on a java poject : https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/Getting-Started, i hope this link help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed this problem with using an empty `Verifier`, something like this:

```
Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken,new Verifier(""));
```

Comment: Hey can you provide code snippet for integrating Withings API using sribe?

Comment: this has been continued here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235908/withings-api-integration-in-android